# CefSharp - Can't access parent of iFrame if parent has an opener

Tags: javascript, iframe, cefsharp

Scenario:

- page1 contains a hyperlink which opens page2 in a separate tab.
- page2 loads content in an iFrame

Both pages and the iFrame content are from the same domain.

If the hyperlink in page1 has `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"` then the iFrame in page2 can access window.parent.
If the hyperlink in page2 has `target="my-tab-name"` then the iFrame in page2 crashes when it tries to access any properties of window.parent.

This does not happen in chrome, it only happens when the page is loaded in a CefSharp browser. I inherited the C# code so I don't know if I'm missing some settings, but I can't see anything obvious.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version is 86.0.241

Comment: Version 96 is the current supported version. You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes.

Comment: This fixed it thank you! Sorry that should have been the first thing I checked before posting!